# Is this reshape of data possible?

Tags: r, melt

I have a data structure that looks like the following:

```
 groupA1    groupA2    groupB1    groupB2    date        text
     0         1          1          1      2013-01-01   the dog
```

For each `groupB` variable, I want to list one row for each column that has a value of 1.
I need to list all combinations of `groupA` and `groupB` where 1s are present into one row, but then also add the date and text to each of those combinations as columns in that row.

Transformed data would appear as:

```
var_groupB  var_groupA  date         text
 groupB1    groupA2     2013-01-01    the dog
 groupB2    groupA2     2013-01-01    the dog
```

I've tried combinations of `melt` and `ddply` but am always left without one of the variables I need.

One thing I tried was `melt(x, id.vars=c("text", "date"))` but then I lose all information about the relationships between `groupA` and `groupB`.

I could accomplish this using a messy loop, but wasn't sure if a `reshape` utility exists that I'm unaware of and could do the job.

Comment: You might find some help in the 'data.table' package, but that looks like a pickle if you ask me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could `melt` twice, once for each group:

```
y <- melt(x, measure.vars=c("groupA1", "groupA2"),
          variable.name="var_groupA", value.name="val_groupA")
y <- melt(y, measure.vars=c("groupB1", "groupB2"),
          variable.name="var_groupB", value.name="val_groupB")
```

That would give you one row for each combination of A and B:

```
        date    text var_groupA val_groupA var_groupB val_groupB
1 2013-01-01 the dog    groupA1          0    groupB1          1
2 2013-01-01 the dog    groupA2          1    groupB1          1
3 2013-01-01 the dog    groupA1          0    groupB2          1
4 2013-01-01 the dog    groupA2          1    groupB2          1
```

Then you could subset this and remove the value columns:

```
y <- y[y$val_groupA == 1 & y$val_groupB==1, ]
y <- y[, c("var_groupA", "var_groupB", "date", "text")]
```

Which gives you what you want:

```
  var_groupA var_groupB       date    text
2    groupA2    groupB1 2013-01-01 the dog
4    groupA2    groupB2 2013-01-01 the dog
```

Of course, if your dataset is more complex than in your example, you can make this solution more elegant by doing the melting and subsetting in a more automated fashion--e.g., detecting the group columns and filling in `measure.vars`, `variable.name`, and `value.name` automatically, perhaps for any number of groups.

Answer (score 2):

The first 2 statements replace each 0 in the first 4 columns with "" and each 1 with the column name giving `dd2`.  The next two statements generate all combinations of `groupA` and `groupB` for each row using `expand.grid` with the result being `dd3`.  Finally  `subset` that to those rows with no `""` entries:

```
newvals <- function(nm) ifelse(dd[[nm]] == 0, "", nm)
dd2 <- replace(dd, 1:4, lapply(names(dd)[1:4], newvals))

combo <- function(x) data.frame(expand.grid(groupA=c(x[1:2]), groupB=c(x[3:4])), 
             x$date, x$text)
dd3 <- do.call("rbind", by(dd2, 1:nrow(dd2), combo)) 

subset(dd3, groupA != "" & groupB != "")
```

This gives:

```
     groupA  groupB     x.date  x.text
1.2 groupA2 groupB1 2013-01-01 the dog
1.4 groupA2 groupB2 2013-01-01 the dog
```